# Git Merge a branch to master on GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-rebase

I've got a basic question here.

I have a branch called: foo
I have created a merge request for "foo".

GitLab says there are merge conflicts with master so I can't auto merge. This is because there's a file called foo.txt that has the same line changed in the master and branch (foo).

What are my options available here? One option is:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout origin/master
git merge --no-ff foo
git push origin master
```

But I wouldn't want the developers to have a direct push access to the master.

How can I make my branch in a merge ready condition so that I can use GitLab's "Auto Merge" option?

Can I know the recommended workflow here?

Comment: Why don't you resolve the conflict? Then you can commit and push. St least in git.

Comment: I resolved the conflict by rebasing my branch onto master. And pushed my branch. But still shows that my branch is unmergeable in GitLab.

Comment: @user1189332 Did you include --force option(or -f) when you pushed to your branch? If not, your rebased commits shouldn't have been pushed to origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resolve the conflicts on branch foo:

```
git checkout foo
git merge master
# resolve conflicts 
git merge --continue
```

Now you have the state intended for master on branch foo. You can merge onto master without any conflicts:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff foo
```

Answer (score 0):

> I resolved the conflict by rebasing my branch onto master.

You need to make sure `master` is the latest of `upstream/master`, not `origin/master`.
Make sure `git remote -v` does show upstream with the URL of the original repo (and not your fork). If not, add one: `git remote add upstream https://url/original/repo`

If you haven't done any commit on `master` itself:

```
git fetch upstream
git checkout master
git reset --hard upstream/master

git checkout yourBranch
git rebase master
git push --force
```